# launching a bitmap

Tags: java, android, animation, android-canvas

I have a surface view class which draws my bitmaps, and I am having a bit of trouble getting an object to be launched from the center bottom of the screen to where the user clicks on the screen, here is a code snippet below 
The onTouch method that gets the coordinates from user touching on the screen, then the run method draws the bitmaps. The rock bitmap is what I need to move from the bottom of the screen to where the touch was made.

```
           public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {


    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        sX = event.getX();
        sY = event.getY();
        fX = fY = dX = dY = sclX = sclY = aniX = aniY = 0;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        fX = event.getX();
        fY = event.getY();
        dX = fX - sX;
        dY = fY - sY;
        sclX = dX / 30;
        sclY = dY / 30;

        break;
    }
    return true;
}

        //the code that draws and updates the bitmaps on screen
        public void run() {
        while (running) {
            if (!sh.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

            canvas = sh.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150);
            if (x != 0 && y != 0)
                canvas.drawBitmap(cross, x - (cross.getWidth() / 2), y- (cross.getHeight() / 2), null);

            canvas.drawBitmap(sling,(canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (sling.getHeight() / 2),canvas.getHeight() - sling.getHeight(), null);
            if (fX != 0 && fY != 0) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(rock, (canvas.getWidth()/2) - aniX,(canvas.getHeight()- sling.getHeight()) - aniY,null);

            }

            aniX = aniX + sclX;
            aniY = aniY + sclY;

            sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

    }
```

Comment: try this http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/handle-ontouchevent-in-surfaceview.html

Comment: Thanks for that link, but I already have the surface view logic I am looking more for how to make an image fire from bottom of screen to where user clicks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some vital thing in your `onTouch()`.

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        sX = event.getX();
        sY = event.getY();
        fX = fY = dX = dY = sclX = sclY = aniX = aniY = 0;
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        fX = event.getX();
        fY = event.getY();
        dX = fX - sX;
        dY = fY - sY;
        sclX = dX / 30;
        sclY = dY / 30;

        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This code has a logic issue. Consider you tap down on 100/100, `sX` and `sY` are set to 100 in the down case. In the up case, you get the up coordinates in `fX` and `fY`, which will be 100, too. This results in `dX = fX - sX` => `dX = 100 - 100`. So your `sclX` will be `0`, too. This means no animation at all.

You should use the middle of the screen as a base for your calculations. Source is the screen center and the destination is your touch.

Comment: wouldn't using a for loop for animation be a possible solution as I have told in my answer.

Comment: It would. A basic animation could be triggered by a draw process like the OP did. Though the basic issue is the missed calculation. You can't animate something if the calculated velocity is 0. I think you missed that part of my answer @Ashwin :D

Comment: I agree that the basic issue is missed calculation. You are right that you can animate if you have the source and destination points, which I think the OP has got wrong. Once he gets the the source and destination right, he can use the for loop.

Comment: I am talking about using the for loop inside the while loop. I am drawing the bitmap from the source to the destination giving an effect of motion. I think that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Ashwin don't take it personally but a for in a while just for some animation isn't good coding. Also the sleep(10) has absolutely no effect (at least on 60hz devices) as each lock/unlock will not be done faster than 60 times per second (means every 16.6 ms). So the sleep will just result in slower fps...

Comment: okay..then what other option is there to make an animation like showing movement of a bitmap? Another question, will increasing the sleep value have any effect?

Comment: I wrote a tutorial series. This is the part about animations: http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-v,188.html